# Compile through VBT giving errors

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel VBA, when I give Compile VBAproject, it doesn't show any error and the compilation is successful.

But I was trying to achieve the same using VBA command like below,

```
Public Function CheckForCompilerErrors()

On Error GoTo errpt
....Excel.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(id:=578).Execute
Exit Function
errpt:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Function
```

Err.Description shows 'Object variable or With block variable not set'.
Before executing this method, I made sure that Compile option is not disabled.

But when I do the same through Compile->VBAProject no issues. How to identify from where the error is thrown when compiled through VBA. It is not highlighting to any code. Just displays the error message.

Comment: Remove the `On Error Goto errpt` and then run the code using F8. Code will highlight the line which is giving you error

Comment: I can't offer a solution, but I can share a finding. Executing that command works only once after it is dirty. Change one character, and you can do it again.

Comment: Does the code really have all those dots ``....` before the line that starts with `Excel`? If yes, remove them.

Comment: In the program, we have 3 add-in's along with VBA project. say a.xla, b.xla, c.xla and VBAProject. The method CheckForCompilerErrors is in a.xla. So actually it is compiling a.xla. But I want to compile VBA Project. I cannot add the code in VBAProject. Is there any way I can compile VBAProject while I am in a.xla.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress excel compiler error from VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157808/how-to-suppress-excel-compiler-error-from-vb6)