# How to suppress excel compiler error from VB6

Tags: excel, vba

I am executing the Excel 'Debug -> Compile VBAProject' from a VBA project like below,

```vb
Public Function CheckForCompilerErrors()
    On Error GoTo compileerr    
    ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.CommandBars.findcontrol(ID:=578).Execute
    Exit Function

compilerErr:
    MsgBox "Compilation failed. Give Debug->Compile VBAProject and fix the compilation errors."
End Function
```

Here after running the `.Execute`, Excel VBA is throwing the error "Compiler Error: User-defined type not defined.".

But actually I want to suppress this Excel VBA error. That's the reason why I added error handler. But in the above case, it is not going to error handler.

Maybe what I am suspecting is, since the `.Execute` got successfully called (which invokes Debug->Compile VBAProject) whether there is any error or not, it returns success and not going to error handler.

Is there anyway, I can suppress the Excel VBA compiler error.

Comment: Typo? `compileerr` `compilerErr:`

Comment: An error handler is a code. In order for a code to run, it must be compiled. If it cannot be compiled, it cannot run. Hence why you cannot "ignore" compile time errors in any language.

Comment: @GSerg, that's not true in the VBA world. You can run code in module with (some)  compilation errors, as long as the method structure is fairly correct.

Comment: @Sam You can run code in a module where some methods have compilation errors, as long as you only call methods that don't. Here the OP calls a method that does.

Comment: I'm still not following the logic of what you're trying to do (you asked pretty much the same thing, yesterday). Compile errors are there for a reason: code that contains them cannot run; there is something wrong with the code *at design time*. The error handler doesn't trigger because the error occurs *before the code runs* - VBA does a check before executing. These can only be suppressed in very special cases, by using conditionals (`#If`). What you've failed to include in either this or the duplicate question you asked yesterday is what code is *causing* the error.

Comment: Note that the compile error may not even be in the code in the project you're working with. It could be in some other vba project that's getting "triggered".

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending the click to the Compile button, there will be an error if the button is unavailable, which it is if you just compiled something. That error you can catch and suppress.
If there is a compilation error, you won't be able to catch it this way.

Comment: How is availability of toolbar buttons related to *compilation* (as apposed to execution) of the VBA project?

Comment: @GSerg, my understanding of this is that the button is available when the code is changed according to VBE, but not all changes. Declaring a new variable or rename a method will make it available, but not changing variable values.  
This way of compiling is based on using the GUI to trigger it, since it isn't available in any other(?) way. It is not a good way.

Comment: I finally understood what you meant. No, the unavailable menu item causes automation error `80004005` which the OP does not have.